# Omit code as if it didn't exist if environment variable is set?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, capacitor

I'm porting a NextJS web app to a web/mobile app with capacitorjs, and I can't use `getServerSideProps` for mobile.

I was wondering if I can use the same files, but omit code based on a environment variable. Something like this for example: (pseudocode)

`APP_TYPE=mobile && npm run build`

```
#IF process.env.APP_TYPE==mobile THEN 

const backendData = await fetch(url);

#ELSE

export async function getServerSideProps(context: { params?: { username: string } }) {
    const backendData = await fetch(url);
}

#ENDIF
```

Then if `APP_TYPE==mobile` the build would run as if the `getServerSideProps` code didn't exist (and the opposite if `APP_TYPE` wasn't mobile).

Are there any methods to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found two interesting packages which do this [Preprocessor.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/Preprocessor.js) and [MetaScript](https://github.com/dcodeIO/MetaScript).

Example (MetaScript):

```
// #ifdef FULL
console.log("Including extension");
// #include "path/to/extension.js"
// #else
console.log("Not including extension");
// #endif
```

Although <s>I found it wasn't the best fit for my project</s> I wasn't sure how to implement it in a good way for my project, so I ended up separating files into `.shared.tsx`, `.web.tsx`, and `.mobile.tsx` instead.